# Setting up TP-LINK TL-WN727N on kali linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-adapter, usb-network-adapter

Yesterday I posted this thread on Stackoverflow but it appeared to be off-topic there and I was redirected to Superuser. I'm posting this thread with unchanged content here. I hope that someone will be able to help me.

*A few days ago I bought a wireless adapter (TP-LINK TL-WN727N)for my virtual Kali Linux. And I have a problem with it's setting up. I read that **TL-WN727N** model using a **RT2870STA Module** (so **rt2870sta** driver and **rt2800.bin** firmware). Do I have to set up **RT2870STA** module or can I use a build-in **RT2800USB**. But command **modprobe -v rt2800usb** does'nt work at all. Device after connection to virtual machine has been recognized in **lsusb** but I can't see any wireless networks. On the one part of stackexchange (I don't remember, maybe ServerFault) I read that I should add device ID to RT2800USB driver. So what should I do?*

Comment: Tell me what's going on after typing `uname -a`?

Answer (score 2):

I works out of the box with monitor and injection support with latest kali 2023 (which is not released yet, i got it from weekly build), so obviously 2022.4 will work without any issue.I tested it just now.

Comment: can you link me to the latest kali build?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wifi adapter with an atheros chip. The TL-WN727N is compatible with Windows and so does not work for Kali. However, the TL-WN722N works for Kali.

Comment: I believe only one version of this model has the Atheros chipset. (V1 has a ar9xxx chip) the other versions I think are realtek or some other junk chipsets. +1

Comment: Windows supports monitor mode for this? I doubt that

Answer (score 0):

It does work, on older kali linux versions, flawlessly as it supports monitor mode.... Even tested it out on my wifi... Try older versions, and also there is no driver on kali for it... But itl work regardless because it's ver3 rt5370 which supports packet injection and monitor mode.. so go ahead and get yourself old kali linux copy.