# tp-lik monitor mode error

Tags: usb, drivers, debian, network-interface

I have a tp link usb network adapter and when I tried to enable monitor mode, I got something saying `SET failed on device wlan1 ; Invalid argument.` as I used `iwconfig`. Later on I found  [this link](https://nooblinux.com/how-to-enable-monitor-mode-on-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3/) to enable monitor mode for tp link, and i ran the commends following

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo reboot

sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo apt install bc

sudo rmmod r8188eu.ko
```

after i ran `rmmod` my interface `wlan1` which is the usb adapter by tplink disappeared and never appeared back again.. How can I make it visible again? and I want to enable monitor mode, thank you for the help.. In case you are wondering, rest of the commands for the tutorial goes,

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus

cd rtl8188eus

sudo -i

echo "blacklist r8188eu" > "/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf"

exit

reboot

cd rtl8188eus

make

sudo make install

sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

also, just in case, I have tp link model `TL-WN727N` and I am running kali linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adapter (TL-WN727N) does not support Monitor Mode on newer kali versions.

The TL-WN722N works for Kali.

I have seen this in the Kali Forums (Discord).

Here is another supporting post.

If you need to consider USB another, consider Panda.

[Monitor mode for Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1146468/setting-up-tp-link-tl-wn727n-on-kali-linux#:%7E:text=It%20does%20work%2C%20on%20older,out%20on%20my%20wifi...)

[USB adapters for Kali Linux](https://www.javatpoint.com/best-wifi-adapters-for-kali-linux)

Comment: althought the answer is great, now how can I make it available for my system again, wlan1 is completely gone, even from `ifconfig` output, I don't want to uninstall and install the whole system again, I guess I should check what `sudo rmmod r8188eu.ko`does, because it disappeared after.

Comment: You need a card that supports monitor mode.  The one you have is for older Kali systems so you need to upgrade the card to a newer one.

Comment: okey, is it possible to downgrade kali ? or should I make a new thread asking this question

Comment: Kali uses rolling upgrades for both security and version upgrades. So you would have find an old version and then soon be out of luck again. Please do not post the same or very similar question. Discouraged here and will most likely be deleted. I really think I have answered your question. I am getting a new Panda card for my own Kali machine.